# Sending Content of ContentPresented as Attached Command Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

In the [MVVM demo app by Josh Smith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), When you attempt to close a tab via the close button on *that* tab (which is **not** the currently selected tab), then it will not close, instead it closes the selected tab.

How can I amend the code so that when I click on the close button for a tab item that not the currently selected one, it closes the right tab?

Note, I have tried using `AttachedProperties` and the following:

```
AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Event="Click"
AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CloseWorkspaceCommand}"
AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext}"
```

where I pass in the `CommandParameter`, but this gets the ViewModel of the hosting View and not the View Model bound to the `ContentPresenter`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: post some strip-down.simplified example:View/ViewModel. Seems like a simple thing... without your code, it's hard to tell where your are stuck. There are too many possibilities. I can code up something as an answer, but that's a waste of time -- might look good but wouldn't help you any, which is the bottom line (besides the points)!

Comment: have you tried just {Bindnig} ?

Comment: @ZSH, spot on mate. That's the answer. If you post this as an answer *with* _why this works_, I will gladly accept! Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: @denismorozov Thanks very much for your time. I didn't post the full code due to its length and thought those familiar with Josh Smiths example MVVM app would know what I am talking about (most MVVM WPF guys have used this example). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using this , it will bind directly to the datacontext of the view

```
AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I edited this to make it a bit clearer, I hope you don't mind :]. Can you also add _why_ this works, as this is not clear to me... Thanks again for your time.